# Switching Activities with different layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Ok, so this may sound like a dumb question, but I am trying to figure out how to have an `Activity` (other than main) control it's layout. I have `MainActivity` link (on a button click) to another layout. This is all fine.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.stands;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView resultView;
Button button1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            //on button click, go to next layout
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now, in my second `Activity`, I want to be able to do something like display text on a button click. But when I implement this, nothing happens. I am confused as to how I can make `SecondScreen.java` control `second_activity_screen.xml`.

**SecondScreen.java**:

```
package com.example.stands;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class SecondScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView tv;
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            //this is where I want to update text field in second_screen_activity
            //but nothing happens
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("Second Activity Button Pressed");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**second_screen_activity.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.stands.SecondScreen$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second Layout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, when I click a button on `activity_main`, I go to `second_screen_activity` and it displays `Second Screen`. On a button click, I want to change `Second Screen` to `Button Pressed`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Intent` to switch between activities. Replace the following line in `onClick()` method of the MainActivity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
```

to this one

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreen.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you never got to your SecondScreen activity. You only changed the layout of MainActivity to that of SecondScreen activity's.

To launch SecondScreen, you need to call startActivity with an Intent of going to SecondScreen. Here:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Remember to add SecondScreen as an activity in your manifest.

The code for setting the TextView's text should work fine.